# How to use cauchy in function space in infinite norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

\begin{align}
\left\| \langle B_{w1},T_{w2}\rangle - \langle B_{w1_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}},T_{w2_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}\rangle \right\|_{\infty}
&\leq \|T_{w2}\| \| B_{w1} - B_{w1_\epsilon}\|_{\infty}+ \|B_{w1_\epsilon}\|\| T_{w2} - T_{w2_\epsilon}\|_{\infty}
\end{align}

How to proof this inequality using
Theorem 1.5 (Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz). Let $\mathfrak{H}_{0}$ be an inner product space. Then for every $f, g \in \mathfrak{H}_{0}$ we have
$$
|\langle f, g\rangle| \leq\|f\|\|g\|
$$
with equality if and only if $f$ and $g$ are parallel.

I am looking for such
$$
|\langle f, g\rangle - \langle k, l\rangle | \leq ?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tbh, I'm not sure what all those indices in your question are but you probably want to do the following:
$$\vert\langle f,g\rangle-\langle k,l\rangle\vert=\vert\langle f-k,g\rangle+\langle k,g-l\rangle\vert\leq\Vert f-k\Vert\Vert g\Vert+\Vert k\Vert\Vert g-l\Vert$$